# Is it possible to clear IntelliJ clipboard history

Tags: intellij-idea, clipboard

I want to clear IntelliJ's clipboard history. I've looked into the documentation but I couldn't find a way to do it.

The reason why I want to clear the clipboard history is I'll be recording a video where I'll be invoking the clipboard history and I don't want the viewer to see unwanted content from the clipboard history. How can I do it?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On mac, hitting `fn` + `detele` removes items from the clipboard history list.

Comment: For a cross-platform application, please consider also answering cross-platform!

Answer (score 3):

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (on mac) / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (on Windows)
the Paste from History dialog appears.

On the dialog, you can select each item in the history and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> button to remove it from the dialog.

You can also select all the lines in the dialog and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> button to remove them all at once

Comment: @HamzaBelmellouki if you only have one element in the history, right?